# function with minumum in geometric mean

Tags: functions, optimization, continuity

I have two real constants (in my case 3 and 15). I need a function that has minimum in the geometric mean and rises to infinity as I come closer to the end points. It only needs be defined on (3, 15).

In other words: I want a fitness function that will prefer the geometric mean and will symetrically (well kinda symetrically) penalize values differing from that point.

Comment: Many functions work, e.g. $f(x) = \left|\frac{x - \sqrt{3 \cdot 15}}{(x-3)(x-15)}\right|$.  Do you want something smoother in some sense?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Great!  I will post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a = 3$ and $b = 15$.  We're looking for a function $f: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{x \to b} f(x) = \infty$ and $f(x) > f(\sqrt{ab})$ for $x \ne \sqrt{ab}$.

There are many such $f$, e.g.:

- $f(x) = \left|\frac{x - \sqrt{ab}}{(x-a)(x-b)}\right|$
- $f(x) = \frac{(x - \sqrt{ab})^2}{(x-a)(b-x)}$